# How did Kyle Reese know what to buy to make pipe bombs?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

After fleeing the police station and checking into the motel, Kyle goes shopping for supplies returning with moth balls, corn syrup etc but how did he know what to buy? I think that in the original timeline Kyle was born after Judgment Day so wouldn't be used to shops or products so how did he manage to find exactly what he was looking for? Is there any deleted scenes or rough draft scripts that explain this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kyle was shown how to make pipe bombs shortly after Judgement Day happened. He would, presumably, be well aware of the common household products you could use (and probably even specific brand names to look for) when making an IED given that the materials he was taught with were almost certainly scavenged from stores and warehouses.

> She locked the door again, her body rush taking its time slowing down,
> and faced Reese. She wanted to tell him she was glad he was back. Very
> glad. But he was putting two grocery bags on the counter and tearing
> them open perfunctorily. Several bottles rolled onto the stained
> tiles. Sarah glanced at them in confusion, reading the labels. “What
> have we got here? Corn syrup, ammonia, mothballs. Umm. What’s for
> dinner?” Reese didn’t rise to the limp attempt at humor. He was
> unpacking another sack filled with ammunition for the .38, road
> flares, tape, scissors, a small pan with a strainer, and matches.
> “Plastique,” he answered, distracted.
>
> “Plastique? What is it?”
>
> “Nitroglycerin, basically. Bit more stable. **I learned how to make it
> when I was a kid.** Sarah stared down at the smelly bottles and sighed.
>
> <sub><sup>[Terminator: Frakes Novelisation](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/The_Terminator_(Frakes_novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: I think OP is questioning how Kyle would know what to buy when he didn't live in a time when there were stores and/or consumer product manufacturers.  Where's he getting moth balls in a post-apocalyptic hellscape?

Comment: @tbrookside  - By raiding shops and supply warehouses, presumably. After the war supplies would run out quite quickly, but how badly do people need mothballs when the world's ended, other than to make nitro?

Comment: I think it's safe to assume there would be products available and someone which the knowledge to put them together but I'm asking if there is any deleted scenes or scripts that explain this scene. I have DVD and BluRay copies but nothing on them talks about this scene.

Comment: @Seamusthedog - No, but in the novelisation there's mention of a group of survivors living in a burned out mall. They have food and consumables to trade, presumably from inside the mall, so it's not like John (and his merry men) are having to build society completely from scratch

Comment: @Valorum it would be good to see if they could do a decent 'post Judgment Day' film or TV series, although I do think TWD do a good job of post-apocalypse life and how quickly it would decent into chaos!

Comment: I would expect Kyle to have been trained.  There would be people who had grown up with stores.  Especially since Sarah Connor would have told John about the whole time travel situation, and both Sarah and John would have had a long time to think about what Kyle would need to know.

Comment: Kyle taught Sarah, who taught John, who taught Kyle, who taught Sarah, who taught John.

Answer (score 1):

In *[Terminator 2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day)* (1991), we see that Sarah taught her son John Connor (when he was a kid before SkyNet took over) how to fight and presumably make improvised weapons and explosives.

She would've had access to all sorts of everyday items to teach him with, and we assume, taught him the generic ingredients too.

Fun fun.

Comment: *"Riding around in helicopters; learning how to blow shit up."*

Comment: She does it in *Dark Fate* too. *"Then you need to be ready."*

Answer (score -1):

If you have a basic (maybe slightly more than basic) understanding of chemistry the product labels will give you all the information you need.

Actually going into a store and buying things may be unfamiliar however going into a bombed out building and scavenging for anything useful would be very familiar and presumably some of the ruins would still have the giant company logo relatively intact not to mention that pretty much everything should have been on a single aisle

Comment: "pretty much everything should have been on a single aisle" - only in the better stores....